# IEC 60335 Creepage for 48 VDC

Tags: power-supply

I am a bit lost with the minimum creepage distances in the IEC60335.

I have to design a PCB, that is supplied with a 3 kV galvanic insulated power supply, providing 48 VDC. Now, according to the norm, 0.5 mm creepage should be used, that is 20 mil and especially around gate drivers very difficult to achieve (I mean the pin to pin distance is already smaller).

So, what do I miss here? Is 0.5 mm only when the system is not SELV/PELV?

About the PCB:
CTI = 175 -> Material IIIa

Pollution Degree = 2

Edit: I'm really interested in how the creepage is applied to components with small footprint, like for example the DRV8320. There are plenty of gate drivers with the same footprints and they seem all not to satisfy the creepage. So what can be done about that? I don't think TI produces ICs that are not compliant on purpose.

Comment: My understanding: If the creepage across a chip's package is already shorter than your required creepage distance, this chip simply cannot be used at the required voltage. Find another one, or add something else in front of it as the isolation device. There are some isolation ICs that are themselves rated for Material Group II instead of III, so that they can be used. One can use a slot cut-out on the PCB to increase the creepage distance on the PCB.

Comment: Well, the problem is, that these ICs I am talking about are for example from TI, and I dont think they are not in compliance with the standards. Lets take for example a motor controller with 48VDC supply, using a DRV8320. All the hardware is put inside a metal cage, which is connected to earth. The System should be in compliance with IEC 60335 and I would like to know the minimum creepage for the 48VDC side. FR4 PCB with CTI 175. Pollution Degree is 2. So, from 60335 it states in table 18, that IEc60664-1 should be used, so 0.16mm it is or am I totally wrong?